# Counting the execution of terminating conditions in Fibonacci series

Tags: java, algorithm, fibonacci

Following pseudo-code, which computes the n-th Fibonacci number:

```
int fibonacci(int n)
{
    if (n == 0){
        print(0)
        return 0
    }
    if (n == 1)
    {
        print(1)
        return 1
    }
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)
}
```

If one calls fibonacci(3), then the following will happen:

> - fibonacci(3) calls fibonacci(2) and fibonacci(1) (the first call).
> - fibonacci(2) calls fibonacci(1) (the second call) and fibonacci(0).
> - The second call of fibonacci(1) prints 1 and returns 1.
> - fibonacci(0) prints 0 and returns 0.
> - fibonacci(2) gets the results of fibonacci(1) and fibonacci(0) and returns 1.
> - The first call of fibonacci(1) prints 1 and returns 1.
> - fibonacci(3) gets the results of fibonacci(2) and fibonacci(1) and returns 2.

In total, 1 will be printed twice and 0 will be printed once.

Objective is to know how many times 0 and 1 will be printed for a given integer N.

INPUT
The first line contains an integer `T`, denoting the number of test cases.
The next `T` lines contain an integer `N`.

OUTPUT
For each test case, print one line of output which contains 2 integers separated by a space. The first integer is the number of times 0 is printed. The second integer is the number of times 1 is printed.

**CONSTRAINTS**

```
1 <= T <= 50
0 <= N <= 40
```

**SAMPLE INPUT**

```
2

0

3
```

**SMAPLE OUTPUT**

```
1 0

1 2
```

**Code**

```
public class Fibonacci {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
static int zero =0,one = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int[] input = readInput();
    for(int i =0; i < input.length;++i) {
        System.out.println(getOutput(input[i]));
    }
}
public static int[] readInput() {
    BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String temp;
    int[] input = null;
    try {
        temp =bufferReader.readLine();  
        int counter = Integer.parseInt(temp);
        input = new int[counter];
        for(int i =0 ; i < counter ;++i)    {
            input[i] =Integer.parseInt(bufferReader.readLine());
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return input;
}
public static String getOutput(int number)  {
    //System.out.println(fibonacci(number));
    return zero+" "+one;
}
public static int fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        //System.out.println(0);
        ++zero;
        return 0;
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        //System.out.println(1);
        ++one;
        return 1;
    }
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
    }
}
```

This works fine for 1st test case but fails for subsequent test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to reset the values of zero and one before calling getOutput.

```
    for(int i =0; i < input.length;++i) {
        zero = 0;
        one = 0;
        System.out.println(getOutput(input[i]));
    }
```